# Arrow function returns an arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I have used to arrow function in JS but while trying to solve async await problem in ExpressJS, I searched around Google and encountered this function:

```
const asyncHandler = fn => (req, res, next) => {
    return Promise
        .resolve(fn(req, res, next))
        .catch(next);
};
```

And this function can be used like this (in ExpressJS):

```
app.use(asyncHandler(async(req, res, next) => {
    await authenticate(req);
    next();
}));
```

From the code, I understand that asyncHandler is a function that receives another function (fn), and that function (fn) returns another function, and inside that function, calling fn.

I don't understand why 3 variables req, res, next is not passed to fn can be used to pass to another function and why fn can returns a function that calling fn.

Comment: asyncHandler is a _higher-order_ function, a middleware "factory".

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hey, could you kindly clarify the last paragraph of your question? I can't understand properly!

Comment: @h-sifat function fn return another function. And that returned function receives 3 parameters req, res and next. But fn function doesn't receive any parameters, how can it passes it to another.

Answer (score 2):

> From the code, I understand that asyncHandler is a function that
> receives another function (fn), and that function (fn) returns another
> function, and inside that function, calling fn.

`asyncHandler` is a function which has an argument `fn` and returns a function.

The argument `fn` is a function which has three arguments `req`, `res` and `next` and returns a `Promise`.

The function that `asyncHandler` returns also has three arguments `req`, `res` and `next` and returns a `Promise`.

`asyncHandler` captures `fn` in a closure (by referring to it in `.resolve(fn(req, res, next))`). This means the function that is returned by `asyncHandler` now has a held reference to that function that was passed to it and can call it later.

So, `asyncHandler` takes a function (which has the signature `(res, req, next) => Promise`) and wraps it in a function (which also has the signature `(res, req, next) => Promise`) which returns a `Promise` which will call `next()` if it fails and pass along the error to the error handler (that's what `.catch(next)` does).

It really just saves some boilerplate where you would otherwise handle the catch in the `app.use()` call `next()` with the error.

> I don't understand why 3 variables req, res, next is not passed to fn
> can be used to pass to another function and why fn can returns a
> function that calling fn.

They are passed to `fn` in `.resolve(fn(req, res, next))`. When all of this actually runs, they are passed from ExpressJS into the function that is returned by `asyncHandler`, from where they are passed to what was passed in as `fn`.

I guess it all gets confusing because there are a lot of anonymous functions being passed around. Not sure if the most confusing part is the arrow function syntax or the closure or the anonymous functions. We can get rid of the arrows syntactic sugar:

```
const verboseAsyncHandler = function(fn) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        return Promise
            .resolve(fn(req, res, next))
            .catch(next);
    }
}
```

Not sure if that helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the first time I know about the concept closure. After reading about it and your comment, now I can understand my problem.